# Can not load image into scrollview for zooming and scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, zooming

I'm trying to load an image into a scrollview and adding gesturerecognizer to the image so it can be zoomed in and scrolled. but somehow i can not get this one to work. I've build the app with the xib file. At first i put the scrollview on top of the view in xib file, but because it didn't work out (gave me a blank black screen) then I tried to put the scrollview programmatically on the .m file. but now it gives me a blank white screen. I'm downloading the image with SDWebImage. Here's my code:

```
    #import "ZoomAndPanViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

@interface ZoomAndPanViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

- (void)centerScrollViewContents;
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;

@end

@implementation ZoomAndPanViewController

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // Get the location within the image view where we tapped
    CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

    // Get a zoom scale that's zoomed in slightly, capped at the maximum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale * 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale);

    // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
    CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // Zoom out slightly, capping at the minimum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale / 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MAX(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale);
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:newZoomScale animated:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CGRect scrollFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    // Set a nice title
    self.title = @"Image";
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blablabla"] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize)
     {
         if (!activityIndicator)
         {
             NSLog(@"setting up the indicator");
             [self.imageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]];
             activityIndicator.center = self.imageView.center;
             [activityIndicator startAnimating];
             NSLog(@"indicator start animating");
         }
     }
                          completed:^(UIImage *uiimage, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
     {
         NSLog(@"download image completed");
         [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
         activityIndicator = nil;
         self.image = uiimage;
         [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
         NSLog(@"image vs uiimage : %f x %f vs %f vs %f", self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height, uiimage.size.width, uiimage.size.height);
     }];

    // Set up the image we want to scroll & zoom and add it to the scroll view


    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=self.image.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    // Tell the scroll view the size of the contents
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image.size;
    NSLog(@"scrollview contentsize %f x %f",  self.image.size.width,  self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:)];
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];
    //[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.imageDownloader setValue:@"SDWebImage Demo" forHTTPHeaderField:@"AppName"];
    SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.imageDownloader.queueMode = SDWebImageDownloaderLIFOQueueMode;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Set up the minimum & maximum zoom scales
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Return the view that we want to zoom
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

@end
```

Any clue in what I did wrong in my codes and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create 2 classes named CustomScroll.h and .m

In CustomScroll.h write

```
@interface CustomScroll : UIScrollView
{

}

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *imageContainer;
```

And in .m write the following Code:

```
@synthesize imageContainer;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

 //self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;

}

// Override layoutSubviews to center content

- (void)layoutSubviews 
{

    [super layoutSubviews];

    // center the image as it becomes smaller than the size of the screen

    CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;

    CGRect frameToCenter = imageContainer.frame;

    // center horizontally
    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

    // center vertically
    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

    imageContainer.frame = frameToCenter;

    NSLog(@"imageContainer.frame.height=== %f",imageContainer.frame.size.height);

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

And In class where you want to scroll the image in .h file import CustomScroll.h and make object like

```
CustomScroll *customScrl;
```

and in your view take ScrollView and put imageview inside it and bind scrollview with customScrl (Don't forget to bind delegate and add UIScrollViewDelegate in .h file)and in custom class tab write CustomScroll as class.

Now in .m file write when you want to display image Or in viewDidLoad:

```
// Zoom image inside Scrol view //
// outputImage is my imageview inside Scrollview
    self.customScrl.contentSize= CGSizeMake(outputImage.frame.size.width, outputImage.frame.size.height);
    self.customScrl.maximumZoomScale=5.0;
    self.customScrl.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    self.customScrl.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.customScrl.delegate=self;
    [self.customScrl addSubview:outputImage];
    self.customScrl.imageContainer=outputImage;

    [self.view addSubview:customScrl];


#pragma ImageZooming Function

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UIImageView *zoomImg = outputImage;
    //NSLog(@"zoom img=== %@",zoomImg);

    return zoomImg;
}
```

Just do as written. It'll definitely work for you also. :)

Comment: hey, I saw your reply just now. I'll try it out and see if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Hey Panu, I don't understand how to bind the scrollview with customsScrl as you told me. Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Bind means connect your scrollView's new referencing outlet with Custom Scroll class's object customScrl just as we are binding object of UITextView *txt to the related textview.

Comment: well, I tried it, but it won't connect. I followed your explanations

Comment: Have you written CustomScroll as class name of ScrollView and made object of CustomScroll *customScrl in .h file? I think you have not written CustomScroll as class under custom Class tag of ScrollView.

Comment: I have done it. but anyway, I've figured out my problem i think. I'm just using the simple synchronous image download for now.What was causing my app to keep giving me a blank screen is that because the image hasn't finished downloading and the scrollview gets loaded. Anyway, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Ohh... I will about to ask you this question if you were still not get your image to be displayed in scrollview. Because it's working nice my side. Anyway it's good that you got solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Just an update for the latest Xcode. This technique works well and is even easier now. Create the CustomScroll class and then in the storyboard add a scrollview and an imageview inside it. Set the Custom Class for the scroll view in the storyboard to CustomScroll and then attach the image view to an IBOutlet (that's instead of the customScrl object above). Also most of the set up code is no longer necessary - just some settings in the storyboard. Tim.